# FactoryBot how to create factories for inter related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to write RSpec tests for legacy ROR app. I have following models

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs to :account
  ...
end
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs to :domain
  ...
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :domain do
    name 'domain-1'
    account { association :account, domain: @instance }
  end
end
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :account do
    name 'account-1'
    domain { association :domain, account: @instance }
  end
end
```

I can create

`FactoryBot.create(:domain)`
but `FactoryBot.create(:account)` fails with Domain can't be blank

Comment: I don't get it. `Domain` belongs to `Account` and `Account` belongs to `Domain`? Why is that?

Comment: I am not sure either why  people who code did that, I am just fixing some things on this repo at the moment and trying to get my head around it. no documentation or proper tests either.

Answer (score 4):

in a normal scenario account and domain has one to many relation. so every domain has one account and account can have many domains.

```
class Domain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  ...
end
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :domains
  ...
end
```

your factories called each other recursively. it should work:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :domain do
    name 'domain-1'
    account
  end
end
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :account do
    name 'account-1'
  end
end
```